# JavaScript: Get Checkbox Value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox

I am trying to write a javascript function that uncheck all other options when the first checkbox "All" is selected. This listitem has an index of 0 in cbxlOption and a value of -1 as shown below. How do I get the value of the checkbox i selected so i can complete the javascript below? Thanks a lot for your help!

```
<asp:CheckboxList ID="cbxlOptions" runat="server" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="-1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 1" Value="0" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 2" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 3" Value="2" />
</asp:CheckboxList>



function UncheckOptions( cbxListID, cbxID )
{
  var checkedValue = null; 
  var cbxListID = document.getElementById( cbxListID );
  var cbxArray = cbxListID.getElementsByTagName( 'input' );

  checkedValue = document.getElementById( cbxID ).value;

          //--uncheck everything else other than the first checkbox(index=0)
  if (checkedValue < 0)  
  {
    for (var i=1; cbxArray[i]; ++1)
    {
        cbxArray[i].checked = false;
    } 
  }
  else                     //--checkedvalue > 0, uncheck "ALL" 
  {
  cbxArray[0].checked = false;

  }

}
```

This is not the exact code (since i am coding in asp.net), but hope this help. 
http://jsbin.com/utuvuy/20/

i am adding the javascript function to each checkbox like this:

```
For Each item As ListItem In cbxlOptions.Items
            item.Attributes.Add("onclick", "UncheckOptions('" & _
                             cbxlStatus.ClientID.ToString & "',this.id);")
Next
```

Comment: kindly share html generated in browser in jsfiddle so we can provide solution.

Comment: Hope this help. Thank you.  http://jsbin.com/utuvuy/20/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are only interested in if "All" is clicked to uncheck all others, you only need to apply your function to that specific checkbox. You can do this in JS without embedding it into your HTML. Also, for a checkbox, you want `onchange` instead of `onclick`.

Give this a try:

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/utuvuy/22/)

```
var all = document.getElementById('cbx0');
all.onchange = function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        UncheckOptions(cbx0);
    }
};

function UncheckOptions(id)
{
    var cbxListID = document.getElementById(id);
    var cbxArray = document.getElementsByTagName( 'input' );

  //--uncheck everything else other than the first checkbox(index=0)
    for(var i=1; i < cbxArray.length; i++) {
        cbxArray[i].checked = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your HTML, add a class to your checkboxes (I used class `cb`) (not the Check All one tho). In your inline change handler, pass `this` as an argument to the function and use the following JS:

```
function doAll(obj) {
    var cb = document.getElementsByClassName("cb");

    for (var i = 0; i < cb.length; i++) {
        cb[i].checked = obj.checked;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cbx0" value="-1" onclick="doAll(this)">All
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/FAbZG/

Comment: Thank you! Will look into the demo.